# What's the alternative for angular.isObject(value) in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm migrating from AngularJS to Angular version 12
In AngularJS, I have the  following operations:

`angular.isObject(value) angular.isDefined(value) angular.forEach(value)`

I want to know the alternatives in angular

Answer (score 1):

Angular does not provide such methods. You can create your own replacements:

for `angular.isObject` you can do:

```
isObject(obj) {
   typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null. 
}
```

for  `angular.forEach` you have `Object.entries` which returns an iterable.

`angular.isDefined` is just

```
isDefined(obj) {
   typeof obj !== null && obj !== undefined. 
}
```